# Find Common elements in two arrays in Linear Time Complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, intersection

I know this type of questions has repetively asked in the community, but my question is little different from the others.

I have faced an Interview on a reputed company today. They asked me two technical questions one of the questions was...

**I have given two unsorted arrays of length say n they asked me to find common elements of the arrays but with an algorithm of time complexity O(n).**

**There is no extra language related support available.**

I have shown them an algorithm with time complexity O(n*log(n)), but they were not satisfied.
I just want to know **If there exists any algorithm of such kind.**

Comment: Put all elements in a hashset?

Comment: Since inserting and searching for a hash table is `O(1)`, just insert each element in a hash table. Check for it is already in the hash table, if so, put into another list (which would be your common elements). That should result in something like a `2n` time complexity (running through elements of both arrays) which is `o(n)`

Comment: @RNar Yes, this may possible but it will take extra space and as I know, hash tables take lot more space than an array. Also they said me there is  **no language support** to use.

Comment: The algorithm in O(n*log(n)) that you came up with was sorting the first array and then doing a binary search for each element of the second in the first one ?

Comment: @AbhishekKashyap yes, the space complexity is larger, but the time complexity is `O(n)`, which is what you are concerned about.

Comment: If you know the range of numbers that you are going to encounter in the array, you can create a vector which counts the occurrence of each number and then iterate over the second to find common numbers. This is a simplification of using a HashSet.

Comment: @RandomGuy Yes, that's true. But you can also find the answer using a better algorithm which does the job after the sorting in O(2n) or O(n).

Comment: @RandomGuy Yes, The approach taken in Counting sort. But they did not said anything about the range.

Comment: @RNar Yes, but they also cares about space complexity. Although that is something I didn't thought that time. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a hashmap to store all the elements of the first array(along with their count to handle the case of repeated elements).

Then traverse the 2nd array and check if they are present in the hashmap.
Ideally time complexity would be `O(2n)` . Since putting an element & retrieving from it is in O(1) time.

You achieve a time complexity of O(n) but your `space complexity` also becomes O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashSet (in C++ it would be `unordered_multiset`) to store the elements of the first array and then iterating over the second find the ones which exist in the HashTable. Since accessing an element has constant time complexity on average, this algorithm will run in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of comments and the other answers I came to the point that there is no possible way to do it in O(n) without the use of **HashMap in C++** or **set in Python** (Which is actually the language support and Increases Space Complexity as well).

So, Here's the solution in python:

```
list1 = [4,2,5,7,1]
list2 = [8,2,4,1,6]

ans =  list(set(list1) & set(list2))
print 'Common Elements: ',ans

>>> Common Elements:  [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void commonElementsInTwoArrays() {
        int[] arr1= {4,6,8,9};
        int[] arr2= {4,6,8,7};
        int i=0,j=0;

        while(i<arr1.length & j<arr2.length) {
            if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]) {
                System.out.println(arr1[i]);
                i++;
                j++;
            }else if(arr1[i]<arr2[j]) {
                i++;
            }else {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Polinaidu. But the proposed solution won't work for unsorted arrays.